# Having FK and PK on same column? cardinality/SQL

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, cardinality

Im learning about databases, I would like to know that is it possible to have a column in a table which gets its Foreign key from another table and at the same time has a primary key?

For example:

X: class, teacher

Y:class(FK,PK)?,teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

This is often used to represent a 1-1 relationship, or many-to-many relationships when there is a composite primary key across columns which are all foreign keys

The most common place I have seen it is in relationships created by ORMs to represent inheritance.

Comment: how can i represent this in SQL?    ADD CONSTRAINT `Class` FOREIGN KEY (`class`) REFERENCES `X` (`class`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE; This is how i add a foreign key but when i try to add a primary key, in structure the foreign key disappears?

Comment: I'm trying to implement it in phpMyAdmin (SQL query)